# Why state transitions does not work in a flex mobile application?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, transition, flex4.6

I want to add transitions when state is changed in a flex mobile app like this:

```
<s:states>
    <s:State name="State1"/>

    <s:State name="resultsState"/>
</s:states>
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    <s:Transition fromState="''" toState="resultsState">
        <s:Sequence duration="2000">
            <s:Fade target="{myTitle}"/>
            <s:Move targets="{[cityNameInput,searchBtn]}"/>
            <s:AddAction target="{''}"/>
            />

        </s:Sequence>
    </s:Transition>
</fx:Declarations>
<s:Button id="about_state" includeIn="resultsState" label="About"
              click="result_state()" icon="@Embed('assets/About.png')"
              />
```

// Function Code is :

```
private function result_state():void{
     currentState = 'resultsState';
}
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare your transition inside the component's `<s:transitions/>` array attribute instead of declaring it inside a `<fx:Declarations/>` block:

```
<s:states>
    <s:State name="State1"/>
    <s:State name="resultsState"/>
</s:states>

<s:transitions>
    <s:Transition fromState="*" toState="resultsState">
        <s:Sequence duration="2000">
            <s:Fade target="{myTitle}"/>
            <s:Move targets="{[cityNameInput,searchBtn]}"/>
        </s:Sequence>
    </s:Transition>
</s:transitions>
<s:Button id="about_state" includeIn="resultsState" label="About"
              click="result_state()" icon="@Embed('assets/About.png')"/>
```

You have plenty of examples at [Adobe Documentation site](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f6a.html).